# Shopware 6.5 Installation with MariaDB failed: General error: 1901 Function or expression 'variant_listing_config'

Tags: mariadb, shopware6

we are not able to install Shopware v6.5.4.0 (PHP 8.2.8) with MariaDb. Tested with version:

```
10.5.22-MariaDB-1:10.5.22+maria~ubu2004 mit PHP-Erweiterung MySQLi
```

and also 10.6.15. Tables are generated in the database, but the installation failed with an error in step 510 from 606:

```
 510/606 [=======================░░░░░]  84%06:51:22 ERROR
[app] Migration: "Shopware\Core\Migration\V6_4\Migration1656397126AddMainVariantConfiguration" failed: 
"An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 1901 Function or expression 'variant_listing_config' cannot 
be used in the CHECK clause of `variant_listing_config`"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [requirements](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/first-steps/system-requirements).

> MariaDB versions 10.3.29, 10.4.19, 10.5.10, **10.5.22**, **10.6.15**, 10.9.8, 10.10.6, 10.11.5 and 11.0.3 are not compatible due to technical problems in these versions.

You should consider updating or downgrading to neither one of these versions.

Comment: Thanks for releasing [v6.5.4.1](https://github.com/shopware/platform/releases/tag/v6.5.4.1) that works around the MariaDB limitation on these versions.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Homebrew I recommend version `brew install mariadb@10.4` it's works well. This will install 10.4.31 to your system.